# Perfecto Mobile - script failure because of busy device

Tags: testing, mobile, automation, qtp, hp-uft

I am using Perfecto Mobile. My script failed because the device was busy. What to do to make it so that the script will work? anybody??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Perfecto Mobile Select Device- it lets you pick up random device that’s available.

[Check it out:](http://help.perfectomobile.com/article/AA-02278)

Comment: WOW! thanks for the quick response!!
check out what i found http://help.perfectomobile.com/article/AA-02265